# Why select_dtypes does not work in this case in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
    import pandas as pd

    import numpy as np

    test_df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2]]*4, columns=['x','y'])

    test_df.iloc[0,0] = '1'
    test_df.iloc[0,0] = 1

    test_df.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
```

I want to know that why column x does not included in this case

Comment: For me, I can see both x & y, which version of numpy and pandas you are using?

Comment: I use numpy 1.11.1 and pandas pandas 0.18.1. It's maybe version problem as you say. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce on Pandas v0.19.2. The issue is when, if at all, Pandas chooses to check and recast series. You first define the series as dtype `object` with this assignment:

```
test_df.iloc[0, 0] = '1'
```

Pandas stores any series with strings as `object` dtype. You then overwrite a value in the next line without explicitly changing the dtype of the series:

```
test_df.iloc[0, 0] = 1
```

But you should **not** assume this automatically triggers conversion to a numeric dtype for the entire series. As far as I am aware, this is not a documented behaviour. While it may work in more recent versions, it is not a behaviour you should assume for a production workflow.